# Where can i find tutorial for Android studio 2.0 latest version

Tags: android-studio

I am beginner in the android world and very keen to learn android.
Where can i  find the android tutorial for android studio 2.0 as i have seen many examples of previous android studio versions, but 2.0 version is very different. I cannot use eclipse android version.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about android studio by using this getting started [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z98hXV9GmzY), watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx3Fn7EowU) to know what's new in version 2.0 .

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a blogpost including a video about the changes made in 2.0: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html

You can also have a look at the Android Studio Overview provided by Google here: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html